# Calculate total price in mutidimensional array

Tags: javascript

im trying to get the total price for a array of products but when i try it, it just return NaN
im kinda new to JavaScript so i might be doing it wrong

so i have a multidimensional array where i keed the data from the products then whit that data i create a table to display the data in the navigator but when i try to add all the price data to total it just say NaN in Navigator but i dont understand why because im using parseInt() method any idea why this could be happening? im running out of ideas to solve this.

JavaScript:

```
let carrito = [];
let continuar;
let figura;
let precio;
let cantidad;
let total;
do{
    figura = prompt("Figura de acción:");
    precio =  prompt("Precio:");
    cantidad = prompt("Cantidad:");
    carrito.push([figura, cantidad, precio]);
    continuar = prompt("¿Continuar?");
}while(continuar != "n");
console.log(carrito)
crearTabla()
function crearTabla(){
    let tabla = "<thead><tr><th>Producto</th><th>Cantidad</th><th>Precio</th></tr></thead>"
    for (var i = 0; i < carrito.length; i++) {
        tabla += `<tr><td>${carrito[i][0]}</td><td>${carrito[i][1]}</td><td>${carrito[i][2]}</td></tr>`
        total += parseInt(carrito[i][2]);
        console.log(carrito[i][2]);
    }
    tabla += `<tr><td>---</td><td>Subtotal:</td><td>${total}</td></tr>`
    document.getElementById("factura").innerHTML = tabla;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Calculadora</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="js/app.js" defer></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <table id="factura"></table>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize `total` as `total = 0;` - if you type `undefined + 1` into the console of the browser dev tools it returns NaN. Without initializing `total` that is the result.

```js
console.log(undefined + 1);

let total;

console.log('Total: ', total += 1);

let goodTotal = 0;

console.log('Good total: ', goodTotal += 1);
```